# Dúvida em consulta JPQL/HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

Preciso fazer uma consulta em HQL e tenho essa entidade Hibernate.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "TB_TIPO_DOCT", schema = "FEP")
 @NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "TbTipoDoct.findAllDocumentosLiberados", query = 
 "SELECT t FROM TbTipoDoct t WHERE t.cdSituCnfr IS NULL ORDER BY 
 t.dsTipoDoct"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "TbTipoDoct.findAllDocumentosNaoLiberados", query = 
"SELECT t FROM TbTipoDoct t WHERE t.cdSituCnfr IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 
t.dsTipoDoct") })
public class TbTipoDoct implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1492325815547842716L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NR_SEQU_TIPO_DOCT")
    private Long nrSequTpDoct;
    @Column(name = "CD_DOCT")
    private Integer cdDoct;
```

O `select` que eu faço é :

```
 SELECT * FROM FEP.TB_TIPO_DOCT WHERE NR_SEQU_TIPO_DOCT = 259;
```

Minha query HQL :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Query query = session.createQuery("from TbTipoDoct tb where tb.nrSequTpDoct= 
:259");
```

Ela está correta?

Comment: Por favor, busque elaborar títulos que remetem a sua dúvida real. Textos como "dúvida em consulta" é genérico demais e não demonstra o conteúdo da sua pergunta.

Comment: Sua query funcionou? testou ela?

Comment: Tente rodar o seu select e caso ocorra erros, poste aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Ela está quase correta.

Para o SQL:

```
 SELECT * FROM FEP.TB_TIPO_DOCT WHERE NR_SEQU_TIPO_DOCT = 259;
```

O HQL/JPQL equivalente, dada sua entidade, seria:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT tb FROM TbTipoDoct tb WHERE tb.nrSequTpDoct = :numero");
query.setParameter("numero", 259L);
```

Perceba que fiz uma correção no uso do valor que deseja buscar, adicionando uma variável `:numero` e o `query.setParameter` para definir o valor da variável.